# Lost USB tethering on Samsung Galaxy Tab A after updating to Android 7.0

Tags: 7.0-nougat, usb-tethering, samsung-galaxy-tab-a

After an update from Android 6.0.1 to Android 7.0 on Samsung Galaxy Tab A (SM-T580, WiFi only), I've lost the USB tethering function.

I need an update to recover this function which is very important for me because I use this tablet only to connect to the remote control of a drone via USB tethering. Without this function, this tablet no longer serves me and the drone too.

Comment: Try using shell commands, do you have root BTW?

Comment: root ? is it like under linux .  i wrote su in shell , give a password and i am under root ?

Comment: Sort of as in 'super user' privileges, after rooting device. Rooting is a different proceedure though, its not available by default like in Linux environments, we have to obtain it by modifying some system files

Answer (score 0):

Check what type of connection it is using, take down the notification drawer and see if there is a "Recharge" notification or something like that.

If so, tap on it and choose the MTP option, then go in the tethering options, and activate it.

Done :)

Comment: hello,

 " Check what type of connection it is using "

how i do that , where i have to look ?  

 before android 7.0 , under android 6.0.1 it was simple , i ran software of my drone , an window opened  and asked  me to enable usb tethering  and it worked . 
  now under android 7.0   the usb tethering function have  gone and i cant enable it anymore so i cant connect to drone . 

 now when i does connect Remote controller  to tablet via usb cable , tablet go only into charger mode .   

thank

Comment: Swipe down the notification bar while connected to the controller, is there a notification about the tablet being in charge only mode?

Comment: indeed there is something else about usb in notification   , but nothing  about usb tethering in notification . I ve tried file transfer via usb but it doesnt work .

Comment: Try to tap that notification, does a menu with different modes for usb appears?

Comment: when i tap i get 4 line: file transfer media , transfer picture , midi connect , nothing . i ve tried four and nothing work.

Comment: choose file transfer media, then go to the tethering options and activate it.

Comment: it is what im tryingto tell . there is no more tethering option under android 7.0 . this option have gone after update .

Comment: Are you sure? Have you checked settings>other(under wireless and networks)>Tethering/mobile hotspot?

Comment: yes this option have gone

Comment: Strange, what ROM are you on? Model of phone? I'm on 7.1.2 and no problem

Comment: 7.0  with samsung tablet tab A 10.1 SM-T580 wifi (2016) .   I ve searched and i'm not alone , lot of people under 7.0 get the same problem , but perhaps this function come back under 7.1.1 and futher .

Comment: Nothing even under wifi?

Comment: Ok, It seems that you can enable it by installing Magisk manager, so you have to root the device

Answer (score 0):

If you enable Developer mode and go to Settings -> {} Developer and tap enable USB Debugging, it allowed me to install an app via USB.

Maybe it will help you.